# Number theory in sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n^3-2x_n^2+2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, divisibility

$x_1=5, x_{n+1}=x_n^3-2x_n^2+2$
Prove that, there is no prime $p=4k+3(k>1)$ and $p\mid x_n^2-3x_n+3$

I think I can have $p\mid t^2+1$ and then I have QED.

But $p\mid x_n^2-3x_n+3$ means that $p\mid (2x_n-3)^2+3=t^2+3$

What should I do next?

Comment: $x_n^3-3x_n^2+2=(x_n+1)(x_n^2-3x_n+3)-1$, may be if we prove $p|x_n^3-3x_n^2+2$  then problem is solved.

Comment: where did you get the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this to be a quite interesting (and challenging to solve) question. It's asking about the primes $p$ where

$$p \mid x_n^2 - 3x_n + 3 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As you showed, multiplying by $4$ gives

$$p \mid 4x_n^2 - 12x_n + 12 = (2x_n - 3)^2 + 3 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $p \neq 3$ (note $x_n \equiv 5 \pmod{72}$ for all $n \ge 1$, with this giving $x_n^2 - 3x_n + 3 \equiv 13 \pmod{72}$), this shows $-3$ is a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $p$.

Next, multiplying \eqref{eq1A} by $x_n - 3$ gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(x_n - 3)(x_n^2 - 3x_n + 3) & = x_n^3 - 3x_n^2 + 3x_n - 3x_n^2 + 9x_n - 9 \\
& = x_n^3 - 6x_n^2 + 12x_n - 8 - 1 \\
& = (x_n - 2)^3 - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This means

$$(x_n - 2)^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

If $n \gt 1$, substituting $x_n = x_{n-1}^3 - 2x_{n-1}^2 + 2$ gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(x_{n-1}^3 - 2x_{n-1}^2)^3 & \equiv (x_{n-1}^2(x_{n-1} - 2))^3 \\
& \equiv x_{n-1}^6(x_{n-1} - 2)^3 \\
& \equiv 1 \pmod{p}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Repeating the substitutions for each $x_i - 2 = x_{i-1}^2(x_{i-1} - 2)$ for $i$ from $n - 1$ down to $2$ gives a product of $0$ or more $x_{i-1}^6$ values multiplied by $(x_1 - 2)^3 = 3^3$, i.e.,

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\right)^6(3^3) \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Multiplying both sides by $3$ gives

$$\left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\right)^3 3^2\right)^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{p} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This shows $3$ is also a quadratic residue. Thus, $3^{-1}(-3) \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ is a quadratic residue, so there's an integer $x$ with $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p} \implies x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Therefore, $4$ is the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $x$ modulo $p$, so $4 \mid p -1 \implies p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. This proves that $p$ *cannot* be of the form $4k + 3$.

Comment: Wait...I am still not seeing how you went from (5) to (6)....

Comment: @Mike If $n \gt 2$, then by definition, $x_{n-1} = x_{n-2}^3 - 2x_{n-2}^2 + 2$, so $x_{n-1} - 2 = x_{n-2}^3 - 2x_{n-2}^2$. Substituting into $(5)$ gives $x_{n-1}^6(x_{n-2}^3 - 2x_{n-2}^2)^3 = x_{n-1}^6(x_{n-2}^2(x_{n-2} - 2))^3 = x_{n-1}^6x_{n-2}^6(x_{n-2} - 2)^3$. At each step, there's an extra $x_i^6$ factor with a smaller index $i$, plus for the same $i$ (with it being $n-2$ at this step) being the factor of $(x_i-2)^3$. Repeating this substitution for each smaller index down to $2$ (so have $(x_1-2)^3$ on right), then using product notation & putting power of $6$ around it gives my $(6)$.

Comment: John Omielian but, shouldn't it be $x^6_{n-1}(x^3_{n-2}-2x^2_{n-2})^a$ where $a$ is 1, not 3?

Comment: Maybe this doesn't really matter as far as showing that 3 is a quadratic residue though...

Comment: OR..should (5) be $ \ldots  \equiv x^6_{n-1}(x_{n-1}-2)^3 \ldots$ i.e., $(x_{n-1}-2)^3$ instead of $(x_{n-1}-2)$? If so then I can follow the rest of this proof...very nice

Comment: @Mike You're right that $(5)$ should be $x_{n-1}^6(x_{n-1}-2)^3$ instead. As you can see, I've just updated my answer to correct that mistake. Thanks for pointing this out and I'm sorry for the trouble & confusion it caused you.

Comment: Its a very nice argument

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the compliment. I spent quite a bit of time thinking about, and trying,  various alternative ways to solve this before I came up with the method I used in my answer.

Comment: It is a beautiful proof to what looks like quite a challenging problem! I wanted to be able to follow it

Comment: @John Omielan, From your solution, I have another one: $$x_{n+1}+1=(x_n+1)(x_n^2-3x_n+3)=\dotso =(x_1+1)(x_1^2-3x_1+3)\dotsm (x_n^2-3x_n+3)$$ and $$x_{n+1}-2=x_n^2(x_n-2)=\dotso =(x_1-2)(x_1\dotsm x_n)^2=3(x_1\dotsm x_n)^2$$ Hence $$x_{n+1}+1=3\bigg[(x_1\dotsm x_n)^2+1\bigg]$$ Thanks for your answer!